# how to override a shared component in spartacus storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to add more information to the price section in the cx-cart-item component:

[cart entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z6IW.png)

However, I don't see an outlet so that I can just attach the component "after" or "before" the price

How do I extend the render functionality? I am thinking:

- copying and pasting the html and ts to just "append" the functionality - when I tried this I get errors indicating that tags such as cx-media does not exist
- find a way to override the component, however, I think this is not possible since I was not able based on the documentation here https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/customizing-cms-components/#custom-angular-cms-components

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838084/cx-media-cx-carousel-not-emitting-data

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer, for now, would be overriding the component, as in the docs you've specified.

You can check the working example here:
https://github.com/tobi-or-not-tobi/spartacus-bootcamp/tree/master/src/app/features/components/banner

In the future, it should be possible to easily replace not only cms components, but also lower-level components.